# Database schema/data saved as xml behind the scenes

Tags: sql-server, xml, database

Using either SQL Server or MySQL, if I were to create a db and create some tables with columns and add some data to those tables, for the user he/she sees a GUI or a diagram or table of their db. But what happens behind the scenes? I always thought that a database eventually breaks down to raw XML but I'm not sure. In other words, somewhere is a file that holds an xml schema of you database along with your data. Is this correct?

For example: If Im working in SQL Server I can right click add new db and add table called: "Item"

Somewhere microsoft has to be storing behind the scenes code of what your database is, so maybe for example?

```
     <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
       <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
            <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>
```

Comment: What raw XML are you talking about?

Comment: The schema of the database you created in management studio for example.

Comment: Why do you think that is XML?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: There is nothing behind the scene related to XML.

Comment: I guess I'm just wondering how all this data/schema info is saved to memory, in what format.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO "Is this correct?" was used in my question. Looking for a yes or no answer, answer doesn't get much shorter that :)

Comment: @TMan Basic knowledge on database helps. But it is more helpful reading a book about database implementation. A short book <Undestanding MySQL Internals> may be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meta-data of a database is stored in system tables. This includes table names, column names and types and generally, all database objects.

In SQL Server you can gain access to these system tables through the [Catalog Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365.aspx)

> Catalog views return information that is used by the SQL Server Database Engine. We recommend that you use catalog views because they are the most general interface to the catalog metadata and provide the most efficient way to obtain, transform, and present customized forms of this information. All user-available catalog metadata is exposed through catalog views.